# ngx-translate import translations after user has autheticated

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I use ngx-translate for my application. We recently were told to not store these translation files in the /assets/* folder due to it having no security around it, and being publicly accessible.

I was curious if anyone knows of a way to load the translationModule or translations themselves until after the app has loaded, and a user has authenticated?

Or within the app.module.ts

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
// return from the app folder not using http, and not from the /assets/i18n, instead of:
return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json?cb=' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how you get the translations, they will never be obfuscated in the FE and they will always be accessible if you request them by and API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `TranslateHttpLoader` does for you. Just add the full URL instead of `assets/i18n/`, like the following:

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'http://YOUR_SERVER_URL/xyz', '');
}
```

You can add this factory to any module, not only the root module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a project 
I need to load my translations data from my API on /getTranslations
But this route needs a bearer token
So, we need to get authenticated first
But Angular load translationModule at same time as Angular is loaded
So we need to wait for user logged before loading translations
To proceed, update the translateLoader by overwriting the getTranslation function

1. Create multiTranslateLoader.ts

```
export class MultiTranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  userLogged$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getTranslation(): Observable<any> {
    return this.userLogged$.asObservable().pipe(
      filter(isUserLogged => isUserLogged),
      switchMap(() => this.http.get<Translation>(`${this.endpoint}`),
          catchError(() => of(null))
        )
      )
  }
}

export function translateLoader(http: HttpClient): TranslateLoader {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

2) use translateLoader factory in your translateModule or appModule

```
NgxTranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: translateLoader,
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        })
```

3. update the userLogged$ subject when user login in your app

```
userLogged$.next(true);
```